# Como mudar o idioma do Git para inglês no Linux?

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu

Eu instalei o Git no meu Ubuntu porém está com o idioma em português. Como posso alterar para o idioma inglês?

Answer (score 1):

No seu terminal, verifique o retorno do comando:

`echo $LANG`

Provavelmente será:

`pt_BR.UTF-8`

Altere o valor da variável da seguinte forma:

```
echo "export LANG=en_US.UTF-8" >> ~/.bashrc
```

E reinicie-o:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: coloquei todos os comandos, mas não efetuou a mudança, o que mudou foi só o pt_BR.UTF-8 para en_US.UTF-8 no meu sistema, mas na hora de usar o git ele continua em português, mas valew por tentar ajudar xD!

Answer (score -3):

Altere o arquivo `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias git='LANG=en_US git'
```